# How do I generate a Sitemap.xml in Wicket?

Tags: sitemap, wicket-1.5

I'm struggling to generate a dynamic sitemap for SEO purposes in a Wicket 1.5 application. I looked at [this example](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/seo-search-engine-optimization.html#SEO-SearchEngineOptimization-CreatingaDynamicSitemap) but couldn't understand what they mean exactly.

I see I need to create an xml page and mount it but then it talks about generating the url list. How do I do this part? Is there functionality in Wicket to get a list of mounted pages? According to that link, it's "very easy" to do this in Wicket 1.5 so I must be missing something obvious.

Any tips or pointers gratefully appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i did exactly this in 2010. there was a wicketstuff-minis project for this.
it could be possible it still works if you dig it out of the archives.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wicketstuff/sitemap-xml

the sources must also be somewhere out there..

this was built for wicket 1.4 but i guess they changed enough to make it no longer work.